# Calling socket.io from rest api in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, socket.io

I am trying to emit a socket.io event from my restful api.

My current setup looks something like this:

app.js
setups an express app and creates all the necessary routes like:

```
var app = express();
...
var routesApi = require('./app_api/routes/index');
app.use('/api', routesApi);
module.exports = app;
```

server.js
creates a server and hooks up both express app and socket.io

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

require('../app_server/controllers/socket.js').socketServer(server);
```

Everything works and I can successfully fire a socket event from the client, process it inside socket.js and emit the results.

However, what I am trying to do is call socket.js method from my restful api and I can't figure out how to hook that up.

Since socket server is initialized inside server.js and my api routing is hooked up in app.js, I am not sure what's the proper way of getting them to talk to each other.

Thank you

Answer (score 13):

You should initialise Socket.io inside the express section (or where you have `app`) so you can save it inside the express request and use it in every route you want.

So in your `app.js` you create the socket and then you save it in app:

```
var socketIo =  require('../app_server/controllers/socket.js').socketServer(server); // Make sure this returns the socketio

app.set('socketIo', socketIo);
```

Now in every route you can do this:

```
app.route('/test').get(function (req, res) {
   var socket = req.app.get('socketIo');
   socket.emit('hello', 'world');
   res.end();
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying and it makes sense, but how would I get server into my app.js?
server is defined inside server.js 
var server = http.createServer(app);
and it needs app to have already been setup to run corretly

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. In my REST API handlers I now can add the two socket-lines, and that will inform all socket.io clients when an incoming REST call has been made.