# Emiting a event to specific socket client inside an Express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets

I'm building a service that convert a socket communication to a Rest one.

So what I have to do is to receibe, by socket, a message from a mobile app, and when this event occur, redirect the message to a third part service trougth a HTTP request and that part is OK.

The problem is when I got the response from this service in an webhook in the same service and have to send to the socket client that originate this (which can be no longer connect at the webhook call).

The actual idea is to join the socket client to a room everytime it connects, and when declaring routes, pass the io inside express `app` so I can use it to broadcast to the room inside the endpoint.

Read [Use socket.io inside a express routes file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file?rq=1) and [Calling socket.io from rest api in node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092427/calling-socket-io-from-rest-api-in-node) from a better view.

The problem is that using socket server instance to emit to a room (that has just one client) can not receive a `ack`, so I don't know if client really get the message.

So, I'm looking for a way to emit event to a specific socket client, inside an Express route, in a way I can't use `ack` to know if it was delivered.

Comment: I dont understand why (and how) your are handling the socket message inside an express middleware. I mean, it looks you are receiving a socket event with some payload data. Then you are making an HTTP request to another service with the payload you received by sockets. And then, with the response data of this service you want to produce a message and send it back to the socket client. I can't see the problem and the "express route" story. Maybe try to edit your question and to provide some code to better understand the problem.

Comment: Hi, infact, que request response doesn't occurs in the same request, it came from a webhook, sometimes 10 minutes later. So I couldn't find a way to get that specific client inside this webhook middleware because it could even not be there anymore.